# Python - how to find numbers in a list which are not the minimum

Tags: python, list, numpy, minimum

I have a list `S = [a[n],b[n],c[n]]` and for `n=0` the minimum of list `S` is the value `'a'`. How do I select the values `b` and `c` given that I know the minimum? The code I'm writing runs through many iterations of `n`, and I want to examine the elements which are not the minimum for a given iteration in the loop.

Python 2.7.3, 32-bit. Numpy 1.6.2. Scipy 0.11.0b1

Comment: So basically what you want to achieve is, for each tuple `(a, b, c)` select `b` and `c` assuming `b` and `c` are greater than `a`, right? (Assuming the tuple is already sorted)

Comment: Yes, but i have no way of knowing which index the minimum value will be in, unless for each iteration i could then order them?

Comment: Since you know the minimum, a simple `[x for x in my_list if x > current_minimum]` would do the trick assuming current minimum is stored at `current_minimum`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can flatten the whole list into a numpy array, then use argsort, the first row of argsort will tell you which array contains the minimum value:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [3,-4,5,8]
c = [6,1,-7,12]
S = [a,b,c]
S2 = np.array(S)
S2.argsort(axis=0)
array([[0, 1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like

```
S.sort()
S[1:3]
```

This is what you want?